# Loading an epub file in webView Android

Tags: android, webview, epub, epublib

I have been using epublib in android to load an epub file in webview. This is my code to load the file

```
public void getEntireBook(){  
    Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
    List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
    int count = spineList.size();
    TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
        Resource res = spine.getResource(i);
        string.append(res.getTitle());

        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.setTitle(string.toString());
        row.setResource(spine.getResource(i));
        contentDetails.add(row);

        try {
            InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line =(String) reader.readLine()) != null) {


                }

            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            //do something with stream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        webView.loadData(line, "text/html;charset=UTF-8",null);
    }
}
```

Some files are loading fine  the files from 20 mb to 70 mb are loading just fine but the files above 90 mb are giving problem either a blank webview is shown or the screen goes black.

Another problem with some are that some files have large text and have rich graphic contents like pictures, decorative fonts. When I load them in webview small dots are shown and when I zoom in the text get scattered.

So I have two questions

1. How to render a large file like 150 mb file in webview
2. How to load an enrich graphic content.

and I have used every webview setting like setrenderpriority high etc, injecting js into webview but I was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

you should render chapter by chapter (pagination). don't render all chapters at a time, that can make laggy on android.

```js
   public void pagination (int page){ 
        Resource res = spine.getResource(page);
        string.append(res.getTitle());

        RowData row = new RowData();
        row.setTitle(string.toString());
        row.setResource(res);
        contentDetails.add(row);

        try {
            InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line =(String) reader.readLine()) != null) {


                }

            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            //do something with stream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        webView.loadData(line, "text/html;charset=UTF-8",null);                       
   }
```